# Get the days between two dates which are in Unix Timestamp

Tags: bash, groovy

Have a file with pull-requests details and has CreatedDate (ex: 1613698170) is in Unix timestamp format.

I want to notify to stake holders, when pull-request is open more than x days.

How to get the no of days between current date and pull-request created date in bash / groovy. So that I will execute this script in jenkins and send out notifications.

Comment: Unix timestamps are just integer counts of seconds from a fixed point in the past. If you get the current timestamp, you can simply subtract the two and divide the difference by 86400.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
def epochMillis = 1598098239000
def now         = new Date()
def then        = new Date(epochMillis)
def days        = now - then

println "then: $then"
println "now:  $now"
println "days between now and then: ${days}"
```

calculates the number of days between now and epoch millis. When executed, the above prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
then: Sat Aug 22 14:10:39 CEST 2020
now:  Fri Feb 19 19:01:54 CET 2021
days between now and file creation: 181
```